# How do I convert an SQL date result to British format (dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, date

I have designed a basic search in ASP/C# for searching through records in a database and have provided the user with these fields which they can use to search: word/phrase, dateFrom, dateTill. So entering "Hello, World!", 05/25/2009, 06/25/2009 respectively will search for a database record with the contents "Hello, World!" which was created between the given dates. Pretty simple stuff.

The text entered by the user into the fields is injected directly into an SQL statement like follows:

```
SELECT r.idRecord, r.recordText
FROM record r
WHERE LOWER(CAST(r.recordText AS VARCHAR)) LIKE LOWER('%" + word/phrase + "%')
  AND r.creationDate BETWEEN '" + dateFrom + "' AND '" + dateTill + "'"
```

So still pretty simple and it works like a charm when the user enters dates in an American format, mm/dd/yyyy. However, it fails when a date in British format is entered like, 25/05/2009. Finally...

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
```

...doesn't particularly help because I don't want to select the date, can a similar statement be used in the WHERE clause?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As a side note: Thou shalt use parameterized SQL. Thou shalt never use string concatenation to create SQL statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the value entered by the user into a `DateTime` data type using the [DateTime.ParseExact method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx). This method allows you to specify the format of the datetime, so you can use `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy`, depending on your user's preferences. Then pass the DateTime value as a parameter to your SQL statement.

Here is a blog post that explains

- how to use parameterized SQL statements and
- why SQL-by-string-concatenation is evil:

[Coding Horror: Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Answer (score 4):

Heinzi's comment isn't really a side-note at all: you should definitely be using parameterized SQL here. That way:

- You don't need to worry about formatting for your date/time fields, because you're not providing a formatted version to the database
- You don't need to worry about SQL injection for your text fields
- You're cleanly separating your code (SQL) from your data (the dates, words etc)

You simply shouldn't include dynamic values in your SQL at all - always use parameters. See [the documentation for `SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I'm new to this and am basically making an existing system more fit to the user's needs. I saw dynamic values being used all over the place so I assumed it was good practice. I will refine my technique.

Comment: @bobble14988: Then please pass on your findings to the other developers - the code is basically open to SQL injection attacks at the moment, by the sounds of it. Show them http://bobby-tables.com/ .