# Converting data entered by user to date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, date

I'm trying to insert data of type 'date' from a textbox on my form to the database.

I want to ensure data entered by the user is stored in the format`'dd/mm/yyyy'` in the database. I have a column in the database of type 'date' but when i enter values of the format above, i get an exception (something like: cannot implicitly convert varchar to type date).

Please how do I convert date entered to the format 'dd/mm/yyyy'. I tried using `CONVERT((varchar,getdate(),103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY])` but i cant figure out where to place it in my code. I'm new to c# and sql server, help please!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert an SQL date result to British format (dd/mm/yyyy)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580184/how-do-i-convert-an-sql-date-result-to-british-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 1):

It's better to not convert the date in SQL, and just pass it back as a date, and then within C# you can structure it however you want

myDate.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")

Comment: Thanks> Please can you explain further?

Answer (score 1):

use `parameterised queries`:

```
DateTime dt;
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text,
        "dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

SqlCOnnection con=new SqlConnection("/*connection string here*/");
string query = "INSERT INTO [TABLENAME](DateCol) VALUES(@DateValue)";
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(query,con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateValue",dt);
con.Open(); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**EDIT:** from your comments :

> i want the date to also be displayed in the same 'dd/MM/yyyy' format
>   in the database

You can can not control underlying Database how it displays or manages your Date in Database but if you want to get the date in format of `dd/MM/yyyy` while reading from database you can try the below:

```
SqlCOnnection con=new SqlConnection("/*connection string here*/");
string query = "SELECT [DateCol] FROM TABLENAME]";
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(query,con);

con.Open(); 
SqlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
   DateTime dt= Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateCol"].ToString());
   string mydateString = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks @Sudhakar! This works but i want the date to also be displayed in the same 'dd/MM/yyyy' format in the database and please could you explain how it works? Thanks!